# "Add a complete current position or education item" won't go away

Tags: support, developer-story

As a SO user for some years, even as I'm not looking for jobs, I thought in finishing my Developer Story page.
Yet, although I included my current position with all fields filled in, the box "Add a complete current position or education item" won't go away, and the Developer Story page reports my profile as "Not finished".

Is this a bug, or I'm doing something wrong ?